# License file does not exist in the specified bundle iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, ocr

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MBInvalidLicenseResourceException', reason: 'License file blinkid-swift_license does not exist in specified bundle'.

This is the error which I'm getting while integrating the sample iOS SDK into my iOS application. The license file is put there inside the main folder only. PFA for your reference.

[image: Please click here for the screenshot with error]

Answer (score 4):

Can you please check if you are using correct Bundle ID in Target - General?

INFO: 
The most common reason why license check fails is that bundle ID does not match the one used in generating the license. As a first step, please double check that this is correct. It also helps to clean project after bundle id change prior to build.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I've used the correct bundle ID in this app. I've rechecked it once again but the error persists.

Comment: Depending on how you added license file in your project, you might need to use different versions of `- (void)setLicenseResource:(NSString * _Nonnull)fileName withExtension:(NSString * _Nullable)extension inSubdirectory:(NSString * _Nullable)subdirectory forBundle:(NSBundle * _Nonnull)bundle` method.

If the license file ends up in the root of your applications's main bundle, you need to set inSubdirectory to ""
If the license file ends in the "License" folder, you need to specify "License" as a subdirectory

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much for such suggestion. The error is resolved.